# Как вывести в верстке ВСЕ данные из таблицы MySQL по user_id?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

У меня есть БД, в которой список новостей, написанные пользователями. Каждой новости присваивается user_id, то есть это id пользователя, который написал эту статью. Как нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог вывести на странице ВСЕ посты этого пользователя прямо в верстке? Как организовать этот цикл? Используется **RedBeanPHP**!

Comment: А какие у вас связи имеются у таблиц? И имеются ли они вообще?

Comment: @InDevX они находятся в одной БД

Answer (score 1):

1. учим SQL и составлем запрос, который выбирает все записи с определенным user_id
2. Идем в документацию по redbean и смотрим, какая функция возвращает массив строк
3. Идем верствку и в цикле выводим все посты.

Comment: Меня интересует именно третий пункт. Как построить этот цикл?

Comment: php.net/foreach

Comment: Вот что-то такое получилось, но не совсем так как надо работает: $userData  = R::getAll('SELECT $userID FROM `articles`'); for($i = 0; $i < count($userData); ++$i) {
     echo 'Тест!';

Comment: У вас с первым пунктом проблемы.

Comment: Вижу. Я переделал. Теперь цикл выполняет echo, но почему-то только один раз:  
               <?php $userData = R::findOne('articles', 'username= ?', array($userID));
   $userArtId = $userData->username;
   for($i = 0; $i < count($userArtId); ++$i) {
    echo 'Тест!';
}
  ?>

Comment: Теперь со вторым

Comment: А что не так? Как-то странно оно работает